# Updating model from form outside of standard create page - goes to create page if form is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I have added a form to my homepage which creates a new instance for the model `links`. This is great, except if you leave the form field empty and hit submit, it forwards you to the new page for the model.

What I actually want is for it to do the same validation check, and tell the user the field can't be blank. I'm not sure why its forwarding rather than raising a validation error- im assuming it has something to do with me creating the instance from a form outside of the typical model scaffold.

Here is the form code:

```
        <%= form_for(@link, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
          <% if @link.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
              <% @link.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

            <div class="urlform">
                <label>Enter link...</label>
                <%= f.text_field :url, :class => "input-medium", :placeholder => "mybookmark.com" %>
                <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn create" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: Could you edit to add your controller code? That's what will be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinksController should define the page to be rendered after model creation fails. You should have right now something similar to:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
    if @link.save
      ...
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
...
end
```

If you change `render new` for `redirect_to root_path` for instance you will get the desired effect.